# Inotify-like solution through NFS

Tags: linux, fuse, inotify, owncloud

We use owncloud to share files. This is a WebDAV-based synchronization system, all file metadata is tracked in a database.

We also wanted our server systems to access these files. We could either mount owncloud through fuse+WebDAV (slow), or mount the data directory directly through NFS. To ensure the metadata database remains synchronized, we watch the filesystem using `inotify` and update the owncloud database accordingly (see [oc-notify](https://github.com/icewind1991/oc-notify) for more info).

This works well when modifying files through NFS.
Unfortunately, modifying files through owncloud also triggers inotify, calling for a second update. This makes the system slow.

Inotify has no way of filtering based on PID (distinguishing between modifications from NFSD daemon and modifications from owncloud). Would one of the following options be possible? Can you give me any pointers on where to start? Are there other options available?

1. Mount ownCloud through WebDAV anyway.
2. Use libfuse to write an intermediary layer. Share that filesystem through NFSD instead. (e.g. [bindfs](http://bindfs.org/))
3. Use a special NFSD callback to keep aware of any changes the NFS daemon is making to files. (does such a thing exist?)
4. Use an alternative to `inotify`, which allows you to track the exact PID of the modifying process. (does such a thing exist?)